# Multivarialbe Calculus Maximum?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm given the equation $z=f(x,y)=1000-9x^2-4y^2$. I'm told that a hiker begins at the point $(10,5,0)$ and climbs a hill south-westernly. I'm trying to find the maximum elevation reached by the hiker.

What I've done is created another equation, $y=x-5$, which satisfies the point $(10,5)$. With this, I plugged it in for $y$ in my $z=f(x,y)$ equation. I was left with $z=900+40x-13x^2$. I calculated the derivative of this and found the maximum point reached to be $x=\frac{20}{13}$. Is this correct or am I going about this completely wrong?

Thanks

Also $z$ represents elevation above sea-level

Comment: Where's the north?

Comment: North is the positive y-axis.

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I've learned them myself but they haven't been taught in my course yet so I'd rather not use them. I solved the question without them though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution looks correct. What you maybe should have been sure of (and maybe are but did not show us), is that the value of $x$ is less than $10$, since the hiker walks in south-west direction.

Here is the picture (the maximal height is somewhat badly shown in red):

[image: hiker]

Comment: If x is less than ten, then wont y have a maximum of 5 based on my equation y=x-5? I solved x to be 20/13. How do I solve for the corresponding y value without using my y=x-5 equation?

Comment: Or is a negative y value okay since I'm simply solving for z?

Comment: You are correct, the values of $y$ should be less than $5$ (they are for the path in the picture). And, indeed, a negative $y$-value is OK. You _should_ use $y=x-5$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The way you solved the problem is very good. However there is a slight variation of the solution that comes from directional derivatives. It's a more direct way:

Given a direction by the unit vector $\mathbf u=\left\langle-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right\rangle$ pointing SW, consider the directional derivative $D_{\mathbf u}f(x,y)=\nabla f\cdot \mathbf u=\langle-18x,-8y\rangle\cdot\left\langle-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right\rangle=9\sqrt{2}x+4\sqrt{2}y$. Considering the path on the $xy$ plane generated by the vector $\mathbf u$ and the projection of the initial point onto the mentioned plane we end up with $y=x-5$. Making the substitution we reach the same result: $x=\dfrac{20}{13}$.